# What is the probability of n-bit numbers being a squared strong semiprime?

Tags: probability, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers

What is the probability among n-bit numbers that a random number is both a square and a strong semiprime?

I know I will need $\frac{n}{\log(n)}$ and the fact that the number of squares is roughly $\sqrt{n}$, but I am not quite sure how the details follow from there.

**Note 1:** An n-bit number being a number with n digits when written in base 2. 
**Note 2:** A strong semiprime meaning that both prime factors have the same number of bits or same number of digits in base 2.

Comment: How many bits do the factors have?  Given a prime $p$, what is the range of numbers you can multiply it by to get an $n$ bit result?  How many of them are prime?  What is the range of values that $p$ can have?

Comment: @RossMillikan Necessarily, they must have the same number of bits...as explained in note 2. Now that I look at all your questions closely....you should probably read the question post first. All your questions are answered. The answer will be in terms of n.

Comment: I was trying to lead you in a way to think about the problem.  I was assuming that you were given $n$.  The factors will be smaller, but you can compute how large they are.  You need to think about carries and whether $n$ is odd or even.  I should have asked given the square of a prime, $p^2$, what is the range of values for $q$ so that $p^2q^2$ has $n$ bits.

Comment: Your title & question body don't quite match. A squared semiprime has the form $p^2q^2$, a square which is also a semiprime has the form $p^2$, where $p,q$ are (not necessarily distinct) primes.

Comment: @PM2Ring My english is not the best. Sorry. Ross I mean, I am aware of that...it is just that I got an answer and it does not quite make sense to me. Just trying to compare it to someone else's and check that I did not miss something. The probability that I get is quite high as n gets bigger, I was expecting it to drop quite fast and it does not.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include those things that you're aware of, and to show us how you calculate these probabilities. They do drop quite fast (just the probability of an n bit number being any kind of square drops quickly), so you've made a mistake somewhere. In the next comment, I'll post a Sage script that does a brute-force count, with the natural log of the probability.

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVUsFuwyAMvUfKP1jqBbasU6udJnWXfcJ2q7qKJE5jNQEGpFX_fpg0S-oT2M_v-RlW8PU7KIc1eOzJOuoRrDOlKqmjQOjzrHGmBwrogjGdB-qtcQEq05ekVSCj_fFKoT06tJ2qsEcdQPkEuDdXpuuwStCp_dMMOlLmWZ7V2ECZlL1oSb7nGcRw5go72B_GWzU4x7w72I6JxjiwQBpS49EpfUKxLWD7M1NwUAN2rUsKXkj4mHgWAI4bYVez4mP6cYQpplGed7CZKxG7VtairoWVY3rBmmctRarNGx8rtu7j9b4DITnLhqhImtEV6qFHpwKKxWaiu8laTOogIr5DLWKPlPNahgIuzMEPwLVFGwcriwGe4CLhZ1pnMpbm2vtpXYe7xVErDbmC7xbvwKSFqmohwnmOU2gLULqGEDGdOYFp0nH-TrfR5vl_QOZZx6_VR7kHZwwpmERc4DU-qji_bKRcayHlH9E1x24=&lang=sage

Comment: $(1)$ A semiprime with two prime factors (can be identical) with the same number of digits in base $2$ is usually called "brillant number (in base $2$)" $(2)$ Whatever variant is correct , numbers with this property must be extremely rare : Either you mean the square of a prime or a number of the form $p^2\cdot q^2$ where $p=q$ is allowed. $(3)$ I wonder why we do not rule out squares if we speak of semiprimes.